# HttpWebRequest StreamReader Progress Percent

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm using C# Console Application.

I'm parsing an HTML page with `HttpWebRequest` and `StreamReader`.

How can I add a `Console.Write` to the `StreamReader` that tracks progress %?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

req.UserAgent = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

string page = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        page = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

---

Similar to `DownloadProgressChanged` with `WebClient` for downloading files, but not web pages.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
wc.DownloadFileAsync(downloadUrl, path);

public static void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;

    Console.Write("\rProgress: {0}%", percentage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this, but you could use the [`HttpWebResponse.ContentLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength?view=netframework-4.7.2) property (which is the value from the `Content-Length` HTTP header) to get the total number of bytes that you can expect. Then you could use [`StreamReader.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) to read a little bit at a time until you reach the the size that you got from `ContentLength`.

Something like this (totally untested):

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://");

req.UserAgent = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

var page = new StringBuilder();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var buffer = new char[4096];
        var numRead = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        html.Append(buffer, 0, numRead);

        var percentage = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(html.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(response.ContentLength) * 100);

        Console.Write("\rProgress: {0}%", percentage);
    }
}
Console.Write("\rProgress: 100%");
```

Now I know that the `Content-Length` header is the number of *bytes* in the response, and I'm using `StringBuilder.Length` to monitor progress, which is the number of *characters*. In Unicode, a single character can equal more than one bytes, so it's not *exactly* right to calculate it this way, but it's close enough.

Comment: Here's a test that will output the download HTML: Original https://rextester.com/AJFD46402 Yours https://rextester.com/SRPC51781 I had to convert the `StringBuilder` to a `String`, so I renamed it to `html` instead of `page`. It seems to stay at 0%, then 100% at the end. It doesn't seem to be downloading all the HTML.

Comment: I said it was untested :) I fixed it up. For some reason `sr.Peek()` isn't good enough to test if it is done. And you have to check how many characters `Read()` returns so you don't add empty characters to the string. And use `double` in the calculation in the percentage.

Comment: It is working great now, thanks. https://rextester.com/OVP80209 Should I increase the buffer char size if the webpage is bigger? Or will `4096` cover most html pages?

Comment: I set it to that since I read in the documentation of the `Read()` method that 4k is the default buffer size for a `Stream`. So if you raise that number here, it will probably still only read 4k at a time unless you find a way to raise the buffer size of the underlying `Stream`. But you can play with it and see what happens.